# Looping through items and read desired elements

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have something like this:

```
<ITEMS ASOF_DATE="6/2/2022" RECORDS="1" CREATE_DATE="6/3/2022" >
    <ITEM>
        <port_name>95512M</port_name>
        <bench_name>LEHSECUR</bench_name>
        <SomeValue>-808</SomeValue>
    </ITEM>
    <ITEM>
        <port_name>95512M</port_name>
        <bench_name>LEHSECUR</bench_name>
        <SomeValue>-808</SomeValue>
        <SomeOtherValue>-808</SomeOtherValue>
    </ITEM> 
    <ITEM>
        <port_name>95512M</port_name>
        <bench_name>LEHSECUR</bench_name>
        <SomethingElse>234</SomethingElse>
    </ITEM> 
</ITEMS>
```

It can have multiple `<ITEM>` items and those can have multiple elements under it for example first item has three elements, second one has four , third one has three in this example.
I want to loop through all of these `<ITEM>` items and read some specific elements that I am interested in. For example `<port_name>` and `<bench_name>`

But I can't figure out how to do the loop. For example `root.SelectNodes("ITEMS")` in my code below isn't what I am **hoping** to be able to loop through its items.

```
 XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(myFilePath.ToString());
        XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
        var lineItems = root.InnerXml;

        XmlNodeList nodes = root.SelectNodes("ITEMS");
        foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
        {
            var somethingElse = node.SelectNodes("ITEM");
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the `Elements()` or `Descendants()` methods to iterate your root element.

*Edited in response to comment:*

If you're looking for something specific, I have found that one of the easiest ways to do this is to write an [Extension Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) for `XElement` that suites your requirements. Here is an example.

```
static class Extensions
{
    public static bool IsPortNameMatch(this XElement xElement, string name)
    {
        if (!string.Equals(xElement.Name.LocalName, "ITEM")) return false;
        var portName = xElement.Element("port_name");
        if (portName == null) return false;
        return string.Equals((string)portName, name);
    }
}
```

---

To test the extension, I have added a fourth `ITEM` to the source with a `port_name` of "UniquePortName". The new console output now reports this as "Found".

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var root = XElement.Parse(source);
    foreach (var item in root.Elements("ITEM"))
    {
        foreach (var entry in item.Elements())
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{entry.Name.LocalName} = {(string)entry}");
        }
    }
    // Find something specific
    var matchItem =
        root.Descendants("ITEM")
        .First(match => match.IsPortNameMatch("UniquePortName"));
    Console.WriteLine($"FOUND:{Environment.NewLine}{matchItem.ToString()}");

}
const string source =
@"<ITEMS ASOF_DATE=""6/2/2022"" RECORDS=""1"" CREATE_DATE=""6/3/2022"" >
    <ITEM>
        <port_name>95512M</port_name>
        <bench_name>LEHSECUR</bench_name>
        <SomeValue>-808</SomeValue>
    </ITEM>
    <ITEM>
        <port_name>95512M</port_name>
        <bench_name>LEHSECUR</bench_name>
        <SomeValue>-808</SomeValue>
        <SomeOtherValue>-808</SomeOtherValue>
    </ITEM> 
    <ITEM>
        <port_name>95512M</port_name>
        <bench_name>LEHSECUR</bench_name>
        <SomethingElse>234</SomethingElse>
    </ITEM>  
    <ITEM>
        <port_name>UniquePortName</port_name>
        <bench_name>LEHSECUR</bench_name>
        <SomethingElse>234</SomethingElse>
    </ITEM> 
</ITEMS>";
}
```

[image: console output]

Comment: Thanks, Is there a way to have more control ? This does loop but for each of those <ITEM> ones, I want to know does it have a <port_name> and if it does, what's its value etc . But currently it does loop through them all but I don't have control to know that ok this one didn't have a <port_name> for example

Comment: No problem! I have made an edit showing one way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Using XML Linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication23
{

    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            foreach (XElement item in doc.Descendants("ITEM"))
            {
                foreach (XElement child in item.Elements())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", child.Name.LocalName, (string)child);
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }

 
}
```

Comment: Thanks but compiler error says doc doesn't have a "Descendants" method defined on it .

Comment: It is xml linq, (xdocument) not legacy xmldocument.